# PreparedStatement Delete in Java

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I have written a code to delete a record in a MySQL database from my Java Program. It compiles and runs it successfully, but the record is still in the datbase. Any suggestions?

```
JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        try {

            Object[] options = {"Yes", "No"};
            Component form = null;
            int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(form, "Do you like to delete the record for Student ID: " +
                    textField_16.getText() + " ?", "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options);

            if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                String mock = textField_16.getText();   

                String sql = "DELETE FROM mockexam WHERE MockID =?";
                PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                prest.setString(1, mock);
                int val = prest.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmDeleteMock, "The record has been deleted successfully.");
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmDeleteMock, "Record couldn't be deleted. Please try again.");
        }       
    }
});

btnDelete.setBounds(45, 235, 89, 23);
panel_1.add(btnDelete);
```

Comment: executeUpdate returns an int, which tells you how much was updatet, get that value and check it.

Comment: Check for `int val = prest.executeUpdate();` and see what value it returns. If you see that you will find out.

Comment: Is the key for your record actually 'MockID'? Note that executing a delete will not throw an error if it doesn't find a record to remove from the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
prest.setString(1, "MockID");
```

You are looking for a MockID equal to MockID I assume you want to delete a entry with a certain ID use:

```
String mockID = "2"; //Set this however you want to set it.
prest.setString(1, mockID);
int val = prest.executeUpdate();
//Check val for what happened.
```

Comment: Hi @twain249 - I am not too sure, what exactly you mean? what do i need to get changed ? and why is it String mockID = "2"; ? where is the 2 being used later?

Comment: I just used 2 as an example this number will be whatever mockID you want to remove.

Comment: i have amended my post with the code as you requested me to change. its still not deleting the row in the database though.

Comment: I have changed to with a variable that i have declared for the textfield value and it works now. thanks :)

Comment: Is there an entry with MockID = 2? What I assume you'll want is to take in what number you want to delete and use that.

Answer (score 4):

You don't indicate what kind of DB you are running against (innoDB or MyISAM, etc) but if you are running against InnoDB, you need to have a `commit()` statement to commit the transaction after your `executeUpdate()`.  Chances are you have something in your log that indicates that your transaction has been rolled back.

```
try {
    Object[] options = {"Yes", "No"};
    Component form = null;
    int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(form, 
            "Do you like to delete the record for Student ID: " + textField_16.getText() + " ?", 
            "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options);

    if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM mockexam WHERE MockID =?";
        PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        prest.setString(1, "MockID");
        prest.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmDeleteMock, "The record has been deleted successfully.");
    }
} 

catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmDeleteMock, "Record couldn't be deleted. Please try again.");
}
```

You're also missing connection an PreparedStatement `close()` calls in a `finally{}` block to ensure that you don't have any leaks in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If no records match your criterion then the SQL will be deemed to have worked. Hence I'd be suspicious of the parameter. What's the type of the column in the database? Could it be a fixed length value and so not match "MockID"?

Comment: if it doesnt match any records, it would pop an error message.